# Returning a set of results by month for the current year in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have the following code and have used it before, but wondered if anyone had a better way of doing it.

Basically I am trying to return the results from a set of data that is date stamped, I need the results to be formatted into months of the current year in order.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT 
    1 AS `month`, YEAR(NOW()) AS `year`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-01-01') AS `from`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-01-31') AS `to`, 'January' AS `fullMonth`, 'Jan' AS `shortMonth`
    UNION SELECT 2 AS `month`, YEAR(NOW()) AS `year` ,CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-02-01') AS `from`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-02-', DAY(LAST_DAY(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-02-01')))) AS `to`, 'February' AS `fullMonth`, 'Feb' AS `shortMonth`
    UNION SELECT 3 AS `month`, YEAR(NOW()) AS `year`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-03-01') AS `from`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-03-31') AS `to`, 'March' AS `fullMonth`, 'Mar' AS `shortMonth`
    UNION SELECT 4 AS `month`, YEAR(NOW()) AS `year`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01') AS `from`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-30') AS `to`, 'April' AS `fullMonth`, 'Apr' AS `shortMonth`
    UNION SELECT 5 AS `month`, YEAR(NOW()) AS `year`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-05-01') AS `from`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-05-31') AS `to`, 'May' AS `fullMonth`, 'May' AS `shortMonth`
    UNION SELECT 6 AS `month`, YEAR(NOW()) AS `year`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-06-01') AS `from`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-06-30') AS `to`, 'June' AS `fullMonth`, 'Jun' AS `shortMonth`
    UNION SELECT 7 AS `month`, YEAR(NOW()) AS `year`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-07-01') AS `from`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-07-31') AS `to`, 'July' AS `fullMonth`, 'Jul' AS `shortMonth`
    UNION SELECT 8 AS `month`, YEAR(NOW()) AS `year`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-08-01') AS `from`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-08-31') AS `to`, 'August' AS `fullMonth`, 'Aug' AS `shortMonth`
    UNION SELECT 9 AS `month`, YEAR(NOW()) AS `year`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-09-01') AS `from`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-09-30') AS `to`, 'September' AS `fullMonth`, 'Sep' AS `shortMonth`
    UNION SELECT 10 AS `month`, YEAR(NOW()) AS `year`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-10-01') AS `from`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()) ,'-10-31') AS `to`, 'October' AS `fullMonth`, 'Oct' AS `shortMonth`
    UNION SELECT 11 AS `month`, YEAR(NOW()) AS `year`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-11-01') AS `from`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-11-30') AS `to`, 'November' AS `fullMonth`, 'Nov' AS `shortMonth`
    UNION SELECT 12 AS `month`, YEAR(NOW()) AS `year`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-12-01') AS `from`, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-12-31') AS `to`, 'December' AS `fullMonth`, 'Dec' AS `shortMonth`
    ) AS `dateFilter`
```

Comment: There are mysql functions to get the month year and so on from a date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you are storing a lot of redundant information.  Consider just using the following table:

```
(
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-01-01') AS `from`  UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-02-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-03-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-05-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-06-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-07-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-08-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-09-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-10-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-11-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-12-01')
)
```

Then, you can easily generate all the other columns you want using MySQL date functions, e.g.

```
SELECT
    MONTH(`from`)             AS month,
    YEAR(`from`)              AS year,
    `from`                    AS first_day,
    LAST_DAY(`from`)          AS last_day,
    DATE_FORMAT(`from`, '%M') AS full_month,
    DATE_FORMAT(`from`, '%b') AS short_month
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: True, however this is meant as a quick paste in addition to a query so that we can build the result set around it. We have a lot of `newbies` who are not used to coding MySql and the functions that it provides, and use Excel connections to get the data. I was trying to find a nice middle ground for them.
I can however see the merits of what you say, lite code etc.

Comment: You could wrap the above query as a view and then you would only have to teach your users how to use that view.

Answer (score 0):

Nice, A big up to [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) for his answer. I swapped over to the following much simpler code.

```
SELECT
    MONTH(`from`) AS `month`,
    YEAR(`from`) AS `year`,
    `from` AS `from`,
    LAST_DAY(`from`) AS `to`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`from`, '%M') AS `fullMonth`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`from`, '%b') AS `shortMonth`
FROM 
(
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-01-01') AS `from`  UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-02-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-03-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-05-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-06-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-07-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-08-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-09-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-10-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-11-01') UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-12-01')
) AS `range`
```